# Horizontal lines during playing video Linux Mint Nvidia 920M

Tags: linux, drivers, video, graphics-card, linux-mint

after installation of Linux Mint I'm suffering with constant horizontal lines during playing video in browsers/players.

I have Geforce 920M card and Intel Core i7 CPU.

I tried to play with installation of different kinds of versions towards nvidia drivers. But it didn't help.

Noveau drivers are now blocked and nvidia-364 is installed.

I tried with different kinds of solutions which are related to this issue, but they didn't help as well.

Here is output of my system configuration:

```
~ $ lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GK208M [GeForce 920M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff

~ $ uname -r
4.5.1-040501-generic

 ~ $ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Default Card 0"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
EndSection

~ $ cat /proc/cmdline 
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.5.1-040501-generic root=UUID=4d977ed5-8946-4ba1-b233-40e4e4d608a7 ro nouveau.blacklist=1 quiet splash vt.handoff=7
```

Could you please help me with this ? I have been trying to resolve it for 2 weeks but without any success so far =(

Comment: One correction: I was able to manage with problem which was related to overwriting of xorg.conf settings by removing ubuntu-drivers-default package and disabling acceleration mode for Nvidia card in xorg.conf: Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    Option "AccelMethod" "none"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is not actual anymore as long as I get rid of issue by using 3.10 kernel.